# Struts2 problem -- values in form not being displayed

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I just got help with the following Struts2 form in my JSP.  No values are being displayed.  Can anyone help?

```
<s:iterator value="bulletins">
    <s:if test="approved == false">
        <s:form action="ApproveBulletin" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><b>From:</b> <s:property value="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><b>Subject:</b> <s:property value="subject" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><b>Date:</b> <s:property value="date" /> <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><s:property value="note" />
                        <s:hidden name="id" value="id" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><s:submit type="button" value="approve" label="Approve"
                        action="ApproveBuletin" /></td>
                    <td><s:submit type="button" value="deny" label="Deny"
                        action="DenyBulletin" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </s:form>
    </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

This is the code from my action class that passes my iterator to my JSP.

```
public String execute() {
    BulletinDAO bulletinDAOInstance = new BulletinDAO();

    List<Bulletin> bulletins = bulletinDAOInstance.getAllBulletins();
    if (bulletins != null) {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("bulletins", bulletins.iterator());
        return "success";
    }

    return "failure";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used to finally get the id variable to render in the hidden tag.  It didn't need much.

```
<s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the "bulletins" iterator in your action class before the forward?

Comment: I believe so.  I just edited the original post to show the execute method(), since I couldn't format it correctly here.

Comment: I don't think it picks up from the session attribute. You need to have setter & getter (setBulletins & getBulletins) with private List<Bulletin> declared in your action class.  
If you need to access session attributes you can try as per the link below
http://www.ukoom.com/accessing-application-session-request-objects-in-struts.htm

Comment: Original URL is here
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html

Comment: I added a getter and setter for List<Bulletin>.  The values are now rendered, but when I check the source code for the rendered page, the value for the hidden field is simply "id", not the actual value in the List<Bulletin>.  Any ideas, anybody?

Comment: From your code the hidden field's value is "id".

 <s:hidden name="id" value="id" />

You need to pick it up from bulletins.

Comment: <s:iterator value="bulletins" status="bulletin">
<s:hidden name="id" value="#bulletin.id" />

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Following code not tested

```
public MyActionClass extends ActionSpport{
  public List<Bulletin> bulletins; //not encapsulated to shorten example, if you do add getters/setters the JSP will continue to work. 
  public String execute() {
    BulletinDAO bulletinDAOInstance = new BulletinDAO();
    bulletins = bulletinDAOInstance.getAllBulletins();
    if (bulletins != null) {
      return "success";
    }else{
      return "failure";
    }
}
```

Struts2 pushes the Action Object onto the value stack, as such you don't need to push it's value onto the session to access it. The session should only hold values that are long lived. Perhaps user preferences... If you really do need to access a session value use `#session.property` see here: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/ognl.html

In the provided code there are some small issues. If you make the action class implement the Preparable interface, you can move the logic to set the DAO into prepare().  It's possible to move the test of bulletins to validate() but for various reasons it's probably better in execute() where it is.